# How to use regex with String.matches in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a String array

```
String[] arrayOfLine = {
    "I.2 Other Interpretive Provisions",
    "I.3 Accounting Terms",
    "Including all",
    "II.1 The Loans",
    "II.3 Prepayments.",
    "III.2 Illegality",
    "IV.2 Conditions",
    "V.2 Authorization",
    "expected to have"
};
```

I want to pick only those array elements which starts with roman.number i.e
starting with I.2, II.1 and so on.

I am trying this, but it is not working

```
String regex = "\b[A-Z]+\\.[0-9]\b";
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfLine.length; i++) {
    if(arrayOfLine[i].matches(regex)){
        listOfHeadings.add(arrayOfLine[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `\b` must be `\\b`. Also, you need to use `.find()` with a `Matcher` object. It looks like you need to find all items that start with the pattern. If yes, use `^[A-Z]+\\.[0-9]`

Comment: `.matches` will attempt to match complete input. Use: `"[A-Z]+\\.[0-9]\\b.*"`

Comment: The example you gave for `arrayOfLine`, can it contain values other than you mentioned ?

Comment: yes it can contain value other than i mention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to find all items that start with the pattern. Use `"^[A-Z]+\\.[0-9]+\\b"` pattern and make sure you run the `find()` method of the `Matcher` object to find *partial* matches inside strings. `.matches()` finds the entire string matches only. Note that `\b` word boundary must be defined as `"\\b"` inside a Java string literal.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/sAZHC6)

```
String[] arrayOfLine = {"I.2 Other Interpretive Provisions" , "I.3 Accounting Terms","Including all","II.1 The Loans","II.3 Prepayments.","III.2 Illegality","IV.2 Conditions","V.2 Authorization","expected to have"};
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]+\\.[0-9]+\\b");
List<String> listOfHeadings = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : arrayOfLine) {
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        listOfHeadings.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println(listOfHeadings);
```

Comment: if i add "2017 ."  ,  "." , "$30","AVAILABLE.”" in arrayOfLine than these are also picked up by pattern.

Comment: @jagga: Please show me your code. [**My solution does not find them**](https://ideone.com/u3mwj3).

Answer (score 0):

You sould try using [Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [Matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). Here is a working example

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+\\.[0-9]");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfLine.length; i++) {
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(arrayOfLine[i]);
        while (match.find()) {
            listOfHeadings.add(match.group());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `regex` for checking roman number with dot is `^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[.]`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class test
    {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] a = {
     "I.2 Other Interpretive Provisions",
     "I.3 Accounting Terms",
     "Including all",
     "II.1 The Loans",
     "II.3 Prepayments.",
     "III.2 Illegality",
     "IV.2 Conditions",
     "V.2 Authorization",
     "expected to have"
     };
     int i=0;
     int b=a.length;
     Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[.]");
     for(i=0;i<b;i++)
     {
         Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(a[i]);
         if (m.find())
             System.out.println(a[i]);
     }
     }
 }
```

Output:

```
I.2 Other Interpretive Provisions
I.3 Accounting Terms
II.1 The Loans
II.3 Prepayments.
III.2 Illegality
IV.2 Conditions
V.2 Authorization
```